# I doing loop on the firebase and new I Not receive data from firebase / firestore itry to get data from my keyValue

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In firebase my document is date and 
I what to check day after day for a month (by my document) if have data if yes give me the day have data

database: collection nutrition -> decedent date(dd-mm-yyyy)

Without the loop its working its going to  getNutritionFromFb(date, dateNum, Foods.BREAKFAST);

but on the loop its not go inside

you can look what I doing...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxDay; i++) {

    if (i < 10) {
        date = "0" + i + "-" + monthFromNum + "-" + year;
        dateNum = "0" + i + "-" + monthFromNum + "-" + year;
    } else {
        date = i + "-" + monthFromNum + "-" + year;
        dateNum = i + "-" + monthFromNum + "-" + year;
    }


    getNutritionFromFb(date, dateNum, Foods.BREAKFAST);
    getNutritionFromFb(date, dateNum, Foods.LUNCH);
    getNutritionFromFb(date, dateNum, Foods.DINNER);
    getNutritionFromFb(date, dateNum, Foods.SNACK);
}


private void getNutritionFromFb(final String date, final String dateNum, final String nutritionType) {
    db.collection(Foods.NUTRITION).document(FireBaseInit.getEmailRegister()).collection(nutritionType)
            .document(date).collection(Foods.All_NUTRITION).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful() && Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getDocuments().size() > 0) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "have nutrition in this data: " + date);

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

                        try {
                            Date mDate = sdf.parse(dateNum);
                            long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

                            calenderEvent.addEvent(new Event(timeInMilliseconds, "Nutrition", Color.GREEN));


                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "error: " + e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Filed receive data " + e);
                }
            });
}
```

I not have error in log, The compiler did not enter into firebase to check the data

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: Without the loop its working I get the data but I add the loop its skip

Comment: I have asked you to add your database structure and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: I not knew how to add database in hare.. and I what to check if I have data in the day I receive .. the loop bass of the month and check day after day if have data

Answer (score 0):

don't you get any log

```
if (task.isSuccessful() && Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getDocuments().size() > 0) {
         Log.d(TAG, "task is successfull ");               
    }
    else{
     Log.d(TAG, "task not successfull ");
    }
```

Comment: No, sorry I not get any log :(